# Kurento Media server client-js for opencv-plugin-sample

Tags: kurento

**What i do:**

1.I downloaded the updated opencv_plugin-sample from the https://github.com/Kurento/kms-opencv-plugin-sample.

2.Run the cmakelist using the cmake-gui and generated the **libkmsopencvpluginsamplemodule.so**

**What i have to do:**

1.Now i need to write **kms-client-js** for the opencv-plugin-sample to run in browser

2.I followed the instruction from the http://doc-kurento.readthedocs.org/en/stable/mastering/develop_kurento_modules.html

```
      cmake .. -DGENERATE_JS_CLIENT_PROJECT=TRUE
```

3.I maually added the js file genrated using the above command to the kurento-crowddetector-client-js,Replace the kurento-module-crowddetector.js path with the OpencvPluginSample.js path in **index.js**

4.When i run the **http-server** from the client path ,i got the following error

```
     KurentoClient.js:15 Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined
     OpencvPluginSample.js:17 Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined
     index.js:64 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'register' of undefined
```

5.What i have to do to move forward?
Is there any documentation to generate the client-js for the opencv-plugin-sample?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to generate **kms-client-js**. From that error, it seems like you are adding a Node module to a browser app. You'll need to [browserify](http://browserify.org/) that module, before adding it to your client code.

Comment: ,Thanks for the reply,I need client-js for javascript for browser(not for javascript for node)

Comment: client-js is already published in [Bower](https://github.com/Kurento/kurento-client-bower), so you only need to browserify the module you generated. Nothing changes when you add a new module, except that you need to include that code generated in the module creator.

Comment: @igcracia,I already run the kms-crowddetector example using the javascript for browser.From the crowd detector client-js folder,
Run 
1.bower install
2.http-server

Comment: I have misunderstood the procedure to generate the client-js and frontend components. Do u have any step-by-step documentation that describes "how to implement client-js and frontend components after developed new module".It would be very helpful for me. Thanks

Comment: If you get a chance,please join this room http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/36966/kurento-media-server

Comment: Wrote some comments there

Comment: yes,if you get a chance pls join the room http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/36966/kurento-media-server